# How to find the right components for the CAN bus signals merging?

Tags: microcontroller, can, canopen

I have 2 CAN connectors from 2 different devices and I want to design something that takes in both the inputs and gives the output on a single connector. In other words, I want to combine 2 different CAN bus lines to a third CAN bus line. I understand that I would need to use CAN transreceivers and CAN controllers with a microcontroller. From my initial research, it seems like there is hardly any microcontrollers available with a in-built CAN transreceiver. Since I want to build this myself, I am lookig for a quick and easy solution. So I am thinking based on Arduino or Adafruit Feather (both of which I have used in the past). These are the few questions from my side on this :

1. What are the benefits of using or not using 3 different CAN transreceivers and CAN controllers with a standard micro-controller?
2. Since there is no logging of data I want to implement, would an RTC be required for this design?
3. Since I want to use 1 DSUB-9 connector (6xCAN, 1 GND, 1 PWR), would there be an issue to use the same power lines for all three CAN lines?
4. What are the things to consider while choosing the right libraries for the CAN bus? I have used [this](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/CAN_BUS_Shield) library in the past in Arduino and I want to know if there are any worthy alternatives.

Comment: https://www.microchip.com/maps/Microcontroller.aspx found 12 mcu's with 4 CAN ports.

Comment: What's the actual MCU software supposed to do? Why do you need a MCU?

Comment: @rdtsc thanks for your suggestion. Like I mentioned I am trying to avoid the micrcontrollers which does not have a community base for development such as Arduino or Adafruit.

Comment: @Lundin this is where the logic of adding the messages from 2 CAN to a single CAN would be programmed.

Comment: And why can't you simply connect the buses? Different baudrates?

Comment: (Microchip SAM families are indeed a great choice for gateway-like applications btw, because they have a DMA-like feature built in with the CAN controller. Incoming data lands straight in RAM without the need to shuffle it from buffers. It's perhaps not very hobbyist friendly, but in case you are actually designing commercial products, you don't want to be some one trick pony Arduino muppets who can only use one tool for every single project.)